# WAQ to represents SalesRep with their quater sales dynamically(Using Pivot)

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Write a query to list SalesReps with their Sales in the following way (columns in the output)

```
SalesRep Name, City, Q1Sales, Q2Sales, Q3Sales, Q4Sales, QAvg, YearSales

Where QAvg = (Q1 Sales + Q2 Sales + Q3 Sales + Q4 Sales) / 4
And YearSales = Q1 Sales + Q2 Sales + Q3 Sales + Q4 Sales
```

Contents of the tables:

```
SalesRep    
--------------------------------------
 column name | data type | constraint
--------------------------------------
 Id          | Int       | PK
 Name        | Varchar   |
 City        | Varchar   |    


SampleData
--------------------------
 Id | Name    | City
--------------------------
 1  | Agent A | Chennai
 2  | Agent B | Delhi
 3  | Agent C | Pune
 4  | Agent D | Bangalore
 5  | Agent E | Patna


Sales
-----------------------------------------------------
 column name | data type     | constraint
-----------------------------------------------------
 SalesRepId  | Int           |  FK to Salesrep table
 QtrId       | Int           |  FK to Qtr table
 Sales       | Numeric(10,2) |


Sample Data
----------------------------
 SalesRepId | QtrId | Sales
----------------------------
 1          | 1     | 1000
 1          | 2     | 2500
 2          | 1     | 3450
 2          | 2     | 4300
 2          | 3     | 230
 2          | 4     | 1367
 4          | 3     | 500
 4          | 4     | 750
 5          | 4     | 450


Qtr
--------------------------------------
 column name | date type | constraint
--------------------------------------
 QtrId       | Int       | PK
 Desc        | varchr2   |


Sample Data
-------------------
  QtrId | Desc1
-------------------
   1    | Q1 FY 14
   2    | Q2 FY 14
   3    | Q3 FY 14
   4    | Q4 FY 14
```

I have made it by using pivot but my query is not dynamic. I have to make it dynamic but how?

My query is:

```
SELECT name, city, 
       "Q1 FY 14", "Q2 FY 14", "Q3 FY 14", "Q4 FY 14", 
       qavg, year_sales
  FROM (SELECT ID, name, qtrid, sales, city
          FROM salesrep
          left outer join sales
            on salesrep.id=sales.salesrepid)
 PIVOT ( 
     sum(sales) for
          qtrid IN (1 AS "Q1 FY 14",
                    2 AS "Q2 FY 14",
                    3 AS "Q3 FY 14",
                    4 AS "Q4 FY 14") 
 ) T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  ( select SALESREPID, 
                          sum(sales)/count(distinct qtrid) as qavg,
                          SUM(SALES) AS year_sales
                     FROM SALES 
                    GROUP BY SALESREPID
                 ) T2
ON T1.ID = T2.SALESREPID;
```

Comment: You have to read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking question

Comment: I am trying to make tables but it is taking in simple text

Comment: here there are three tales SalesRep, SalesRepId, QtrId and I have specifed the column name and data type of that also added sample data

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove either [mysql] or [oracle] depending on what database server you're using (MySQL or Oracle Server).

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't do it fully dynamic in SQL query, because as you can read [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238) _the names, number and types of all selected columns must be known at parse time_. But you could do something like in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd4c6/1), where there are always four quarters in each row, but divided depending on column qtr.description.

Comment: there is a one single problem in the query if there is no entry in the table in sales it is still counting that quarter in avg..I only need average of the quarter in which sale is done. if there is null than it should not count.

Comment: @PonderStibbons can give a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select year, id, name, city, q1, q2, q3, q4,
    (nvl(q1, 0)+nvl(q2, 0)+nvl(q3, 0)+nvl(q4, 0)) 
      / (nvl2(q1,1,0)+nvl2(q2,1,0)+nvl2(q3,1,0)+nvl2(q4,1,0)) s_avg,
    (nvl(q1, 0)+nvl(q2, 0)+nvl(q3, 0)+nvl(q4, 0)) / 4 s_avg4,
    nvl(q1, 0)+nvl(q2, 0)+nvl(q3, 0)+nvl(q4, 0) s_sum
  from (
    select substr(q.descr, 1, 2) qtr, substr(q.descr, 7, 2) year, 
           sr.id, sr.name, sr.city, s.sales
      from salesrep sr join sales s on s.salesrepid = sr.id 
      join qtr q on q.qtrid = s.qtrid)
  pivot (sum(sales) for qtr in ('Q1' Q1, 'Q2' Q2, 'Q3' Q3, 'Q4' Q4))
  order by year, id

==============================================================================

YEAR ID NAME       CITY          Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    S_AVG   S_AVG4  S_SUM
---- -- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- -------- -------- ------
14    1 Agent A    Chennai     1000  2500                 1750      875   3500
14    2 Agent B    Delhi       3450  4300   230  1367  2336,75  2336,75   9347
14    4 Agent D    Bangalore                500   750      625    312,5   1250
14    5 Agent E    Patna                          450      450    112,5    450
15    1 Agent A    Chennai     4455                       4455  1113,75   4455
```

1) Part of your question is: *Where QAvg = (Q1 Sales + Q2 Sales + Q3 Sales + Q4 Sales) / 4*. I think you should always divide by `4` - like I did for column `S_AVG4`. But if you want to divide by the number of quarters where sum of `sales` is not null then use syntax for column `S_AVG`.

2) In SQL queries number of columns must be known at parse time. There are PLSQL workarounds for dynamic solutions, I already posted link in comments.